# Openni_tracker with a simulated kinect in Gazebo

Tags: ros

We use gazebo to simulate the kinect sensor. Is there any option to run the `openni_tracker` package without using the real sensor. When we try to run it

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch load_driver:=false depth_registration:=true camera:=camera
rosrun openni_tracker openni_tracker
```

we have got the following error:

> InitFromXml failed: Can't create any node of the requested type!

thank you all in advance